# Three state workflow template

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am new to sharepoint and have started learning Sharepoint 2013(foundation).

I created three state workflow thru out of the box (not from designer) on a document library and is working fine as expected.
My question is, I have to create more than 25 types separate document libraries for different types of documents(creater, reviewer, approver can be different for each).

So Is it possible to copy and paste or Create template of workflow once and apply on different doc libraries?

**Edits**:

Finally I got solution

I did this by Saving Document library as template and then create New Document Library using this template. This template contains all of the custom columns you created as well workflow also.

Answer (score 1):

I did this by Saving Document library as template and then create New Document Library using this template. This template contains all of the custom columns you created as well workflow also.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes you can reuse it for other document libraries.**

Most workflows are made to run against either a list app or a library app. The most common workflow, one that is in every version of SharePoint, is called the three-state workflow, and it's made to work with the issue tracking app. So I'm going to begin by creating a new issue tracking app for customer issues. I'm creating a URL, so maybe c-issues. That'll be good. And we'll fix that when it's time to do that. The reason this works beautifully with this three-state workflow is that when I create a new item in this list and the form opens, I have an issue status that has three states.

Kindly check below link to understand the scenario.

[Customize the three-state workflow](https://www.lynda.com/SharePoint-Online-tutorials/Customize-three-state-workflow/466190/494730-4.html)

Comment: I gone thru the link, they are not explaining how to copy paste or create template or any other way to create once and apply on multiple list/document libraries. Did u understand my question?

Comment: It is using the same method like reusable workflow but in this case you need to make sure the columns are available which you are using in your list or library.

Comment: dear, i can keep the columns same in each library, tell me how to apply workflow created on first library will be apply on others?

Comment: remember I am not using resuable workflow, using Three State workflow

Comment: I know that. That's why i mentioned here in comment that the method is same like reusable workflow.

Comment: Hardik, I am new to sharepoint (foundation)can u please explain me in brief how to do this?, if possible thru three-state workflow only. Reusable workflow is not visible to me in sharepoint foundation version.